# C# Generic return type of method

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to write a generic getRecord method that I can use in my data calls.

I keep getting null exception errors.  Is there a way to new up T?

```
    public static T GetSingleRecord<T>(string storedProcedure, List<ParameterInfo> parameters, string connectionString) where T: new()
    {
        //T output = default(T);
        //T output = (T)Convert.ChangeType(T);

        var p = new DynamicParameters();
        foreach (var param in parameters)
        {
            p.Add("@" + param.Name, param.Value);
        }

        using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        return  conn.QueryFirstOrDefault<T>(storedProcedure, p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
```

Comment: *"Is there a way to new up T?"* `T output = new T();`

Comment: Where are you getting an exception, and exactly what does the exception message say?

Comment: I am calling it this way:    ApplicationUser result = DapperHelper.GetSingleRecord<ApplicationUser>(proc, p, conn);   I get a NullReferenceException.  Object not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I got it.